# Data value retrieve is not the same as in database - Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, model

I've created 3 tables. User, student and lecture. The user could be a student or a lecture depending on the type on the user table. Student type = "std" while lecture type = "lct". The problem is, when i log in as a lecture, the type value will always be "std" eventhough in the database it is "lct". New in Laravel. Thanks

**User table**

```
user_id    |  password  |   type  
a123       |   1234     |   std     
b345       |   1234     |   lct
```

**Student table**

```
student_id |   name
a123       |   david
```

**Lecture table**

```
lecture_id |   name
b345       |   Mr Steve
```

**User model**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public function student(){

    return $this->hasOne(student::class,'student_id');
}
public function lecture(){

    return $this->hasOne(lecture::class,'lecture_id');
}
```

**Student model (Lecture model also has this but with PK = lecture_id)**

```
protected $primaryKey = 'student_id';
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public function index()
{   
    $type = Auth::user()->type;
    dd($type);
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you save them in your users table there is where there is the problem.

Comment: @TheodoryFaustine i register them with the register.blade.php and the registercontroller will insert them into the db. I dont think thats the problem cause when i registered it, the data inserted in the db is correct.

Comment: what is the output of `dd($type);`?

Comment: In your each relationship you should provide proper path to the model something like this `hasOne('App\Phone')`

Comment: This `Auth::user()` will only return for authenticated user or the user who's logged in ? does current user is Lecture ?

Comment: And please don't mess up with usertable `protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';` this has to change, please in your user table keep columns as with default name like `id, email, password` otherwise auth might not work in some cases

Comment: dd type will always display "std" eventhought i log in as lecture @InzamamIdrees

Comment: show the code where you login as lecture or student?

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Just assuming

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
public function student(){

    return $this->hasOne(Student::class,'student_id'); // It should be Student not student I guess (Capital S)
}
public function lecture(){

    return $this->hasOne(Lecture::class,'lecture_id'); // Lecture not lecture
}
```

Check you model class name once.

Comment: tried it, still the same. the class name is small letters btw